# Unifying bots and einstein-chatbot tags?

Tags: discussion

There are two tags - `einstein-chatbot` and `bots` which basically are about the same thing and users use them interchangeably. Why not unifying them?

Comment: I don't know this feature at all so would love more input from the community. Are there bots that are not Einstein chatbots? Is there any contextual variation in how bots are used or deployed that might merit different tags?